# GWT : hello world in Request factory

Tags: gwt

i am looking for some simplest program like Hello world written in Request factory , I've searched a lot ,also looked in google code ,but couldnt understand any code .

if some one could provide me with a real simple program in request factory

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently writing my first program using GWT-RequestFactory, and indeed it seems that a good background in GWT and reading several articles is needed. [These tutorials](http://www.mikemitterer.at/infopoint/programmierung/gwt-requestfactory/) would be a good starting point.